# How to see hot network question time of an unedited question?

Tags: support, edits, hot-questions, revisions-list

When a question becomes a hot network question, the time it became such is shown in the edit history of the question. You can replace the last part of the URL with `revisions` to see.

I just came across [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/61760), no edits yet so there's no button to click to see edit history.

I tried to "replace" the last part of the URL with revisions in several ways:

```
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/revisions
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/why-are-there-no-papers-about-stock-prediction-with-machine-learning-in-leading/revisions
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/timeline
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/why-are-there-no-papers-about-stock-prediction-with-machine-learning-in-leading/timeline
```

No luck, all the pages just redirect to or show the original question.

How can I see the time it became hot network question?

Comment: [Timeline](https://quant.stackexchange.com/posts/61760/timeline#history_7b442d23-9681-4360-a032-d3f6b2fe3dad) 

Comment: You can *also* see the revisions by using the same `/posts/<pistID>/*` URL, but with `revisions` instead of `timeline`. So, [`https://quant.stackexchange.com/posts/61760/revisions`](https://quant.stackexchange.com/posts/61760/revisions) for the question in which you're interested. Both the `posts` `/timeline` and `/revisions` URLs work for every question and answer, but the timeline is a bit easier to get to when there's not more than one revision, due to always having the timeline link below the post voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct URL is `posts` instead of `questions` (and `timeline` not `revisions`):

```
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/timeline
```

And it can always be opened via the bottom "history" button on the left:

[image]

Comment: this image lacks a freehand circle

Comment: @Luuklag extremely good point, I am ashamed of my negligence  No wonder I'm also the type of guy who would post a duplicate question....